# Cassandra nodejs driver, how to update data correctly

Tags: cassandra, datastax-node-driver

I am new to Cassandra and I don't quite know if my data model is correct. I have tried to create it based on the queries I want to make in my application. I want to create and update book objects and I want to find books by author and by publish date. I am using the DataStax Node.js Driver for Cassandra (using Typescript) and here is my schema so far:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS books_by_author (
    author_id UUID,
    book_id UUID,
    book_name TEXT,
    date_published TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (author_id, date_published);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS books (
    book_id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    book_name text,
    book_description TEXT,
    date_published TIMESTAMP,
    author_id uuid,
    author_name TEXT,
 + many more columns for book details);
```

Making author_id and date_published as primary key I was able to make queries with the nodejs driver and with help from the DataStax documentation:

```
const q = cassandra.mapping.q;

const results = await this.bookMapper.find(
          {
            authorId: '1', datePublished: q.and(q.gte(start), q.lte(end)), // given timerange for publish date, works fine
          },
          docInfo,
          options);
```

The above code works well; I can get the list of books by author and by specifying a date range when publised. The bookMapper is mapping both tables (books_by_author, books) so I am using it to make all my DB queries.

Then I ran into issues. I created a book in my application but I gave it the wrong publish date and I would like to change that. So, to see how it could be done, I created a unit test that saves a book to the DB, then tries to use bookMapper.update to update the book's datePublished property. Here's some pseudo code on what I tried to achieve:

```
const bookId = '123uuid';

const existingBook = new Book({
    id: bookId,
    name: 'The Book',
    datePublished: '2020-07-03T13:00:00.000Z',
    description: 'Book description',
    author: {
      id: '1',
      name: 'A. Author',
    }
});
... // insert existingBook to DB and read book details from DB using bookMapper.get({bookId})

const modifiedBook = new Book({
    id: bookId,
    name: 'The Book',
    datePublished: '2020-07-02T13:00:00.000Z', // modified publish date
    description: 'Modified book description', // modified the book description as well
    author: {
      id: '1',
      name: 'A. Author',
    }
});

await this.bookMapper.update(modifiedBook); // update the book

await this.bookMapper.get({bookId}); // returns the book with data from existingBook, not modifiedBook

await this.bookMapper.find(
          {
            authorId: '1', datePublished: q.and(q.gte(start), q.lte(end)),
          },
          docInfo,
          options); 
// query with author id, returns a list of 2 books, both the existingBook and modifiedBook ??
```

As you can see, the update actually created a new book row to the DB and now I have 2 books instead of 1. And I have no idea what is the correct way of updating that data. I tried to use batching:

```
let changes = [];
changes.push(this.bookMapper.batching.remove(exisitingBook));
changes.push(this.bookMapper.batching.insert(modifiedBook));
await this.mapper.batch(changes);

const book = await this.bookMapper.get({bookId});
--> book is null!
```

Using batching to remove and insert seems to work so that remove is the last call to DB, it doesn't matter in which order I add those statements to my changes array, and it removes the book causing my last get statement to return null.

I wanted to use batching to make the operation atomic. I don't want to end up in a situation where I first delete the existing book and then insert the new book in separate DB calls without batching because if some error occurs after delete but before insert, then I will have lost my book data from the DB.

My question: What is the correct way to update the book data when the updated property happens to be part of a primary key? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well known "feature" of Cassandra - in the batch the both statements are getting the same timestamp, so the `DELETE` operation wins over the `INSERT`.  The only solution to fix that is to explicitly set timestamps for every operation, with timestamp for `DELETE` lower than `INSERT`.  I'm not Node.js developer, so it how it should be looking in pseudo-code/CQL (Node.js mapper should support setting custom timestamp on statements):

```
TS=currentTimestampInMicroseconds
BEGIN BATCH
DELETE FROM table USING TIMESTAMP TS-1 WHERE PK = ... US;
INSERT INTO table (....) VALUES (....) USING TIMESTAMP TS;
APPLY BATCH;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will try setting the timestamp for the operations next week when I continue with this task. Although at a quick glance it seems that the Node.js mapper does not support timestamps when using batching..

Comment: You need to try to set timestamp for individual statements

Comment: see description of the timestamp field for `QueryOptions`: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/4.5/api/type.QueryOptions/